# How to add more than one product tittle

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I add more than one product tittle as you can see in the picture for Wordpress/Woocommerce ?
[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add fields in the backend hook into the `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` or the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title`.

You can find more guidelines [here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/).